# Quarkus syslog message format

Tags: elastic-stack, syslog, quarkus

I am usung quarkus to log some events from application to elasticsearch as syslog, look at

```
quarkus.log.syslog.enable=true
quarkus.log.syslog.endpoint=elkhost:7001
quarkus.log.syslog.protocol=udp
quarkus.log.syslog.use-counting-framing=false
quarkus.log.syslog.app-name=MYAPP
quarkus.log.syslog.hostname=MYHOST
quarkus.log.syslog.level=ALL
quarkus.log.syslog.format=%m%n
```

Notice `%m` is only thing to log, no another data. RFC format is default. And from Kabana i see

`<14>1 2020-02-29T11:43:06.001+03:00 MYHOST MYAPP 9348 test - test messagee`

How must I set quarkus logging to write ONLY message sent? Only "test massage" without any text left of message.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Syslog [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424), this format is not customizable in the way you expect.

Syslog message is composed from mandatory parts :

- PRI
- HEAD
- MSG

So you can not reduce a syslog message to its MSG part only.
Quarkus is not the restriction here but RFC 5424.